# Can I use BRL for the US visa fee in Asuncion?

Tags: visas, exchange, paraguay

I am travelling to Asuncion, Paraguay as an American. Paraguay levies a reciprocity fee of $160, which must be paid in cash.

I can pay this upon arrival, and [multiple](https://paraguay.visahq.com/) [sources](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/paraguay.html) mention USD, but it's not 100% certain.

I am currently in Brazil; a quick calculation says the fee is roughly R$ 500 at current exchange rates; will I be able to bring this amount to pay?

If not, might there be an ATM from which I could withdraw USD? I'd like to avoid paying the exchange bid-ask if possible.

Comment: https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294080-i7051-k9094974-VISA_Airport-Asuncion.html. just found this topic and it's got me worried... wish me luck....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they do not accept any currency but US Dollars and Paraguayan Guarani. Further, the dollar bills must be in mint condition; all denominations were accepted (I paid with $100×1, $20×2, $5×3, and $1×5)

Luckily, there is an ATM in the room from which you can withdraw guarani upon arrival; I used this to account for my $100 bill being rejected due to a mark in the margin (see photo). Note that there may not be change in guarani or dollars.

[image]

[image]